# Change the color of inner circle in the polar plot in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am making a polar plot and this is the output of my code

[image]

Everything is working fine, I just need to know how can I change the edgecolor of the inner-most circle (which is black in the image)

Comment: Or, you could plot a white circle without a border on top of that circle...

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
ax.spines['inner'].set_color('w')
```

there are 4 border line in polar axis:

- polar
- start
- end
- inner

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).